# Remote internet via VPN

Tags: internet, vpn

I heard that one can get internet using VPN from a server anywhere. Is this possible and how is it done?

Comment: You have to be connected to the internet in order to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Virtual Private Network (VPN) is used to link two private networks into a single virtual network by passing data encrypted across a public network (usually the Internet) or an untrusted third party network.

A typical use-case is for linking a small sub-office to a company's main office or for linking a mobile worker to the main office network for access to file-servers, mail and other resources.

The VPN can be created by running software on two computers that are connected to the public network. Alternatively, many routers can act as VPN endpoints and can set up VPN connections as needed.

```
                   (       Internet          )
  ,---------,    (                             )    ,---------,
  | private |---------------------------------------| private |
  | network |   (    encrypted VPN "tunnel"     )   | network |
  '---------'     (                            )    '---------'
                    (                        )
```